# Monitor journald for further processing

Tags: api, logging, systemd-journald

I'm writing a service application that will read log entries from several sources, parse them into a simpler format and allow analytics and statistics on them. The most important of the sources will be journald.

I understand that a command like `journalctl -o json -f` will give me all the data I need. I can open that as a subprocess and read from its stdout stream. An additional `--since "..."` allows me to catch up from the last received entry, for example after a reboot or service restart.

But what about the performance of this. Is it recommended to use the `journalctl` command for such background and permanent monitoring activity? Will it eat too much memory, disk I/O or runtime to keep the `journalctl` instance running in the background "forever"? Or should I rather find a more direct API into journald? I've also read about systemd-journal-upload but I'm not entirely sure whether it can catch up after a reboot. It also sends all data through HTTP which has its own protocol overhead, although my service will be written with ASP.NET Core so it can already accept HTTP requests.

I'm targeting Ubuntu Server 20.04 and calling from .NET Core 3.1, if that's relevant. Journald is configured to use persistent storage. Everything runs locally; for now I'm not collecting logs from remote machines.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Monitoring journal to trigger some email alerts. I started from https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.Systemd library, but give up because it goes down into C/linux interop...

Comment: @StefanoV I'm using this package, too, but I understand it is for applications only. A service can notify Systemd or log *into* Journald. It should only be a shallow wrapper for the native functions. I don't believe it can *read* from the system logs.

Comment: Investigate whether there is a wrapper in your language of joice to sd-journal, the C APi for retrieving journal entries.  For example, python has the systemd.journal package.  You could potentially write a small python service wrapper for systemd.journal package.  For example https://github.com/digitaltrails/jouno includes code which forwards from systemd.journal to DBUS.  But I do also think that journalctl -f is a reasonable way to proceed.